# Triangulation of a quotient space

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $X$ be the quotient space of the triangle $ABC$ obtained by identifying each of the oriented sides $AB$, $BC$, and $CA$.

I need to calculate the Euler Characteristic of this space but I am trying struggling  to find an appropriate triangulation of $X$ , and I'm also not sure how to visualise this quotient space.

Could someone help explain a method of finding a triangulation?

Comment: I think if you triangulate $ABC$ with the second barycentric subdivision, this should be enough to induce a triangulation on the quotient. (One subdivision might be enough.) If you're only interested in the Euler characteristic you can also compute it via homology, or via a cell structure (whose definition isn't as strict as a triangulation)

Comment: To try to visualize this space, it is sometimes called the "$3$-fold dunce cap" and it's homeomorphic to the space obtained by attaching a disc to a circle by wrapping its boundary three times around.